# MLE of weibull distribution with survival data

Tags: maximum-likelihood, survival, likelihood, weibull-distribution

I would like to ask about estimating parameters of Weibull distribution (a, and b)

I am trying to code likelihood of weibull distribution with survival data $(T_i, \Delta_i),$ which I believe is: $(ab)^{\sum\Delta_i} \times \prod((T_i^{b-1})^{\Delta_i} \times \exp(-aT_i^b)).$

I am trying to type this formula in R and try to find likelihood of weibull distribution.

However, I get a very weird results such as likelihood is approximately 0 for most prediction, and I get negative log-likelihood values even when I input the parameters I used to generate random data.

Can someone please help me in implementing likelihood and log-likelihood of weibull distribution under survival context?

I want to use this likelihood to approximate a and b based on data generated using Newton-Raphson method.

By the way, the question asks to set parameters for Weibull distribution on our own and set (right)censoring = 50%, and I did not have any further information, so I assumed Delta_i is bern(0.5). Based on data generated from Weibull, I need to define likelihood, log-likelihood function, and use it in Newton-Raphson.

If you guys are too busy, please implement likelihood and log-likelihood only.

Here is what I've tried:

```
X.3 <- rweibull(1000, 2, 9)

Delta.3 <- rbinom(1000, 1, 0.5)

L <- function(x) (x[1]^(-x[2]))^(sum(Delta.3)) * prod(((X.3)^(x[2] - 1))^Delta.3 * exp(-x[1]^(-x[2]) * X.3^x[2]))

l.v <- function(x) sum(Delta.3)*log(x[1]^(-x[2])) + sum(Delta.3)*log(1/3)+ ((x[2] - 1) * sum(Delta.3*log(X.3))) - x[1]^(-x[2])*sum(X.3^(x[2]))
```

The weird exponents are from transforming textbook definition of Weibull parameters to R's definition of Weibull parameters.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to CV. Please note that this is a MathJax-enabled site. Please use the facility to typeset your equations. For a quick help, please visit this [page](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/instructions-on-how-to-use-latex-on-crossvalidated).

Comment: I have tried to edit the equations. Please check whether they rendered correctly.

Comment: How is defined the censoring?